# Redirect to another page in windows 8 app

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-8

I am developing a windows 8 application using JS. I am using following jquery ajax code to post values to online server and check if result from server is success string then redirect to another page in local server. But its not redirecting to another page defined.

**JQuery Code**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.domain.com/process/login.php",
    data: { email: email,password: password},
    success: function (result) {
        if (result == "success") {
            location.href = "home.html";
        }
        else {
            $("#content2").html(result);
        }

    }

});
```

I am getting output as **success** in my windows 8 app where selector id is **content2**, Can anyone tell where am i doing this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing Windows 8 application using WinJS, Please follow [this link](http://www.csell.net/2012/11/13/31-days-of-windows-8-day-13-navigation/#navigating-between-pages).

```
WinJS.Navigation.navigate(<PAGE_URL_HERE>);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am not familiar with WinJS, So prefer only JS or Jquery

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing result value from server output to boolen 1 instead of string **"success"** and did following modification in jquery code and it worked.

```
 if (result == 1) {
                        location.href = "home.html";
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#content2").html(result);
                    }
```